# UIView.animateWithDuration or UIScrollView.animateWithDuration - how to pause at current status

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiviewanimation

I am using these (code block 1 and 2) to move UIScrollView with animation from beginning to my endPoint 
(x: 0 to 1000, in this example)

***Code Block 1:***

```
UIScrollView.animateWithDuration(Double(5), delay: 1, options: (UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear | UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState),
                            animations: {
self.myScrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(1000, 0)
                            },
                            completion: {
                                finished in
                                if(finished)
                                {

                                }
                        })
```

***Code Block 2:***

UIView.animateWithDuration ...

The problem is that cannot pause at the current x point.

I've tried them already and didn't work for me.

- importing QuartzCore framework
- self.myScrollView.layer.beginTime = 0.0 on completion
- CATransaction.begin() and CATransaction.commit()
- self.myScrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations(). This stops the animation totally then UIScrollView is going to endPoint (to x:1000)

Also animateWithDuration is cancelling scrollViewDidScroll, so can't get the current position. In addition, can't get the current position in Pause function by the same reason.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView)
{
scrollView.bounds.origin.x
var pos:CGPoint = self.layer.presentationLayer().bounds.origin
}

func StopSlidingByBeginDragging()
{
CATransaction.begin() 
self.myScrollView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Basically I need to pause when I touch or scroll UIScrollView manually it should pause then resume. I found this animation to sliding animation, maybe you can suggest something different.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this custom `UIScrollView` class along with the `UIViewController` code.

```
class TouchScrollView : UIScrollView
{
    var animatedScrollOffset = CGPointMake(0, 0)

    func startAnimation()
    {
        UIScrollView.animateWithDuration(Double(5), delay: 1,
            options: (UIViewAnimationOptions.AllowUserInteraction
                | UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear |
                UIViewAnimationOptions.BeginFromCurrentState),
            animations: {
                self.contentOffset = self.animatedScrollOffset
            },
            completion: {
                finished in
                if !finished {

                }
        })

    }

    func stopAnimation()
    {
        let offset = self.layer.presentationLayer().bounds.origin
        self.layer.removeAllAnimations()
        self.contentOffset = offset
    }

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

       if let gestures = self.gestureRecognizers
        {
            for gestureRecognizer in gestures
            {
                if let swipeRecognizer = gestureRecognizer as? UIGestureRecognizer
                {
                    swipeRecognizer.cancelsTouchesInView = false
                }
            }
        }
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.stopAnimation()
    }

    override func touchesEnded(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.startAnimation()
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate,UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var scrollView : TouchScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollView.frame.width, 10000)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollView.animatedScrollOffset = CGPointMake(0, 1000)
        scrollView.startAnimation()
        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_: UIScrollView) {
        println("begin dragging")
        scrollView.stopAnimation()
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDragging(_ : UIScrollView, willDecelerate decelerate: Bool) {
        println("end dragging")
        if !decelerate
        {
            scrollView.startAnimation()
        }
    }

    func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ : UIScrollView) {
        scrollView.startAnimation()
    }

}
```